# Loop with the each function through the html

Tags: jquery

my codes is as below,

```
   $(document).ready(function(){

            $.each($(".mainloop"), function (e, index) {
                alert($(this.durum).text());
                alert($(this>a).text());
                alert($(this>img).text());

       }); });
```

and html is like this.

```
 <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true"  data-filter-placeholder="M" data-inset="true">



     <li data-icon="arrow-r" class="mainloop">
     <a class="btnLW" href="wtf.html">
    <img class="myimg" src="pic1.png" />
    <h2 class="durum">durum1  </h2>
   </a>

     </li>

     <li data-icon="arrow-r" class="mainloop">
         <a class="btnLW" href="wtf2.html">
   <img class="myimg" src="pic1.png" />
    <h2 class="durum">durum 2 </h2>

   </a></li>

</ul>
```

I need to reach the a>href,img>src and .durum values.

Comment: have a look at [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/75n5E/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.find()` here:

```
alert($(this).find('.durum').text());
alert($(this).find('a').text());
```

Also the `img` don't have `.text()` method, I believe you want to get its `src` instead, if that is the case, you can use `.attr()`:

```
alert($(this).find('img').attr('src'));
```

Also it's better to use `console.log()` instead of `alert()` for debugging.

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/557HL/)**

Comment: not possiable to reach like this??  alert($(this>img).src());

Comment: You need to use `$(this).find('img').attr('src')`

Comment: `this > img` would be `$(this).children('img')`.

Answer (score 0):

```
alert($(this).find('a img').next().text());
```